# Error: Source path does not exist: resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

I'm trying to get an APK file from a Ionic project with the "`cordova build --release android`" command on a **Mac** and it doesn't work as I get this error

> "Error: Source path does not exist:
>   resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png"

. 
Anyone knows where it might come from?

Here is the copy of the config.xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.rise268787" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>RISE</name>
<description>
    Discover music as you go
</description>
<author email="infos@olivierlam.fr" href="http://olivierlam.fr/">
  Olivier Lam
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.1">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="Rise" />
</plugin>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*.youtube.com" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you verify that the file is inside your project folder. check in the resource folder outside your www folder.

Comment: Yes it is in the ressources\android\icon folder.

Comment: Verify that the file named drawable-hdpi-icon.png is inside your resources folder as in the path : `resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png`

Comment: Yes it is inside.

Comment: Can you add a copy of your config.xml file of the project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124226/discussion-between-sangeeth-kumar-s-g-and-theof).

Answer (score 70):

I had the same error, After running

> ionic resources

Or

> ionic cordova resources

(Based on the ionic version of your application)

it went away.

The problem was that I had Windows-style slashes (backslashes) in the path of the icon, i.e. the error I had was this:

> Error: Source path does not exist:
>   resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png

So, converting backslashes into slashes resolved it for me.

Hope this help to you and the others looking for same problem. It all happens  because using different machines[mac & windows] for development of project like mac and windows.

Comment: i had the same error but  the help was in this link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2355 the answer of PeterWahba commented on May 30

Comment: `ionic resources` Fixed the issue for me.

This command will generate the icons and splash screen images for each platform setup in the project.

Docs : https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/

Comment: Command has been updated to `ionic cordova resources` in Ionic 3

Comment: You need to be logged in to execute ionic cordova resources. On a build server you need to run ionic login USERNAME PASSWORD first

Comment: This worked for me as well ( ionic cordova resources )

Answer (score 15):

You can add your resources again by running:

```
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because you have:

```xml
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

in your `config.xml`, and when you run `ionic cordova resources` it is only generating the resources for portrait orientation.

Answer (score 3):

Do not forget to add files in the `resources` folder.

The source image for icons should ideally be at least 1024×1024px and located at `resources/icon.png`. The source image for splash screens should ideally be at least 2732×2732px and located at `resources/splash.png`. If you used ionic start, there should already be default Ionic resources in the resources/ directory, which you can overwrite.

You need to use this formats: `.png`, `.psd`, or `.ai`.

You can use https://code.ionicframework.com/resources/splash.psd as a template for your splash screen and https://code.ionicframework.com/resources/icon.psd for a icon.

Answer (score 2):

In config.xml, I changed the resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi.png to resources resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi.png

Note the slash change.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the resources tags from the config.xml and run `ionic cordova resources -f`. It will auto-generate all your necessary resources and tags. And you should be able to build the app.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error using the way similar to Fakan. You just need to change the icon tag with src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi.png" outside the platform tags to "resources\icon.png" to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Just try to find the path of this resource inside the Ionic structure. 
Sometimes, or in some versions, this path may be like this:

Your resource:

```
resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi.png
```

Try this:

```
res/android/icon/drawable-hdpi.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your icon if it is actually saved as ".png". Not as ".PNG". Right-click on it and hit Properties.

If it wasn't, edit your icon and save it with a file extension ".png".

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />` in config.xml file and run ionic cordova resources.

Problem is when you run ionic cordova resources it is only generates the resources for portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your config.xml file. Mine looks like this:

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash density="hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
</platform>
```

Note that res/ is relative to the project root directory. The filenames may be different at your end.

Answer (score 0):

A quick alternative answer:

```
Error: Source path does not exist: resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png
```

Is the same as

```
Error: Source path does not exist: resources\android\icon\foreground-hdpi-icon.png
```

or

```
Error: Source path does not exist: resources\android\icon\background-hdpi-icon.png
```

> And any other in that category

The command looks for base files namely **icon-drawable.png** |  **icon-foreground.png** | **icon-background.png**

---

in location ***android/resources*** so the best thing is to include those images in android/resources then re-run `cordova build --release android` or `ionic cordova resources android` to check

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem worked, but it is a little peculiar.

I created the following files and put them in the "resources" directory:

icon.png, icon.jpg, icon.jpeg, splash.png, splash.jpg, splash.jpeg.

If you use --verbose, it'll tell you the dimensions each file must have. For example, icon.png must have 512x512 pixels. And splash.png must have 1920x1920 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just need to change my `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` which are supported by the Ionic project in environment variables then the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

In config.xml, I changed the resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi.png to resources resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi.png

Comment: those two paths are identical

Comment: these are the same